# event.preventDefault with Firefox and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, firefox, preventdefault

I know there are lot of threads with this question but mine is a little different I will explain why.

**Background:** 
I am using angular JS to submit a form. I have a groovy tags like below in my GSP

```
<form action="formAction" class="form-horizontal" id="UserForm" name="UserForm"
            useToken="true" ng-app="angularApp"  ng-controller="angularController" novalidate="" ng-submit="onSubmitClick();">


 <input type="button" name="next" value="submit"
                                id="submit" />
```

( Actually a submit tag in Groovy but StackOverflow doesnt allow me to write that )

This is a form tag with Action and ng-submit specified.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

When the submit button is clicked "onSubmitButtonClick()" function is invoked and if the form is invalid it needs to prevent submit.

onSubmitButtonClick is defined in angular Controller. Now the problem is Angular JS will submit the form as long it finds the "action" URL defined. I cannot remove value for that URL because it is coming from serverside at run time. so I started using event.preventDefault().

event.preventDefault doesnot work in Firefox so I started passing event in function call **onSubmitButtonClick(event)** and I realize that for Firefox this comes as undefined.

So, is there a way to access event in firefox ? I cannot use 'return false' or event.returnValue=false because Angular just ignores them. So, I need to get event.preventDefault to work.

Below is how onSubmitButtonClick code looks like :

> $scope.onSubmitButtonClick=function(evt){ 
>        if($scope.UserForm.$invalid) 
>       {
>
> ```
>     var browserObj=browserDetectFunction();  
>     if(browserObj.browser=='Firefox') 
>     {   
>           evt.preventDefault(); // this throws evt undefined error in Firefox 
>     } else 
>    { 
>       event.preventDefault(); 
>    } } }
> ```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly answering your question, but a different route to take that should work (looking at your code):

```
<input type="button" name="next" value="submit"
                            id="submit" ng-disabled="UserForm.$invalid" />
```

Or you remove your submit button if invalid, and replace it with a non-functioning button:

```
<input type="button" name="next" value="submit"
                            id="submit" ng-if="UserForm.$valid" />
<button type="button" name="next" value="submit"
                            ng-if="UserForm.$invalid" />
```

Comment: I appreciate that you took time to reply but I cannot disable the button. That is the business requirement.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, the business requirement is to make a button that won't submit the form if it's invalid, but not to disable the button?

Comment: Yes sounds weird but yes..thats the requirement. If user clicks on the button when the form is invalid, we should apply some CSS to make it even more evident that form is invalid. But button should be enabled at all times.

Comment: would that work... technically two buttons, but one of them just doesn't do anything.  then you can style it to look exactly the same?